# python2.7-colorbar: how to set color scale tick font?

Tags: colorbar

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,N) # x value
y = np.linspace(-2.0,2.0,N) # y value
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z1 = np.exp(-(X)**2 - (Y)**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X*10)**2 - (Y*10)**2)
z = Z1 + 50 * Z2
z[:5, :5] = -1
z = ma.masked_where(z<=0,z)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(),cmap=cm.PuBu_r)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cs) # add colorbar
plt.show()
```

the result is shown as follow:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwVaO.png)

question: how to set color scale tick font?

Answer (score 0):

just add `cbar.ax.set_yticklabels` line of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,N) # x value
y = np.linspace(-2.0,2.0,N) # y value
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z1 = np.exp(-(X)**2 - (Y)**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X*10)**2 - (Y*10)**2)
z = Z1 + 50 * Z2
z[:5, :5] = -1
z = ma.masked_where(z<=0,z)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(X,Y,z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(),cmap=cm.PuBu_r)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cs) # add colorbar
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.values, fontname="Arial Black") #this line has been added, i am setting font as Arial Black
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please modify the values as per your need

Comment: Thank you. but my question is how to change the tick font, such as changing to 'Times New Roman', not font size.

Comment: Done. Check now